# remove ii7 from windows 7 ultimate

Tags: iis-7

i recently had trouble with wamp running properly in my windows 7 ultimte.(it was running properly some days ago) so i tried to install ii7 in my os but it didn't seem to work great though, so i uninstalled it. Now i have managed to install wamp properly but when i access localhost, it opens ii7 page. i can't figure out whats wrong?

can anyone help. I want to remove that ii7 page from localhost and want wamp page in it.

And when i try to access another page by typing "http://localhost/info.php" it shows page with this headings "Server Error in Application "DEFAULT WEB SITE""

Comment: How did you uninstall IIS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The thing is that IIS is still taking your port 80, which is the default web hosting port. Try and access the IIS control panel and change the port from there.

Comment: Christoffer Madsen is right, at least for my computer. I just had to find the Internet Information Services (IIS) Manager and could disable IIS from a section called Manage Server. Then, restart your browser and make sure your cache has cleared if this doesn't resolve.